# GCD-based login timeout sometimes fires at next login attempt

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I had some trouble formulating the Question title, please make an edit if you have a better alternative.

I have a Login procedure to which I add a timeout:

```
private func startTimeout() {
    self.timeoutActive = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20) { 
        [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        if weakSelf.timeoutActive && !weakSelf.loggedIn {
            weakSelf.onError("Login timed out")
        }
    }
}
```

I have designed the Login procedure so that if we for any reason need to log in again (for example after logging out, or after the login process determined that there missing or wrong credentials), we end up in the same instance of the class that performs the Login.

Now, as far as I see, we can never prevent a scheduled block from executing, only prevent it by using some flags, which is what I have done with the timeoutActive flag. This works like a charm.

However, I run into a problem if the second Login is timed exactly so that the Previous dispatch block executes after the new Login process is started (When the new login procedure is initiated, the timeoutActive flag is once again set to true). The new Login receives a Timeout that is not correct.

I have been thinking about different ways to solve it, and tried a few, but couldn't get any of them to work.

I had an idea to use `performSelectorAfterDelay` instead of GCD, which is cancellable, but not available in Swift (3).

I also played with the thought of having some unique block ID with a list of blocked block IDs - but it just seems overkill.

I also had an idea about comparing the current dispatch time (.now()) in the block with the original deadline (.now() + 20) and see if it matches, but I don't know how exact this deadline is and it feels unstable.

The only idea I'm left with is making some kind of Task like object around the Login procedure itself, with the timeout included and create a new instance of that task for different Logins. Seems like a bit of work and I'd prefer if I found an easier way.

Has anyone encountered this type of situation before and have a solution?

Comment: `performSelectorAfterDelay` is available in Swift3, it just had its name changed to `perform(...)` like the other perform selector methods.  You can also create and then `asyncAfter(...)` a `DispatchWorkItem` which is cancellable.

Comment: Xcode only showed me 3 perform(...) methods before, where the "after" parameter wasn't available. My Bad.  The DispatchWorkItem is new for me and I'm trying it out. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you @dan it worked perfectly. I posted this as an answer since you didn't, but if you post an answer instead I will remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I made from Dan's comment on the Question:

```
private var timeoutBlock: DispatchWorkItem? = nil

private func startTimeout() {
    self.timeoutBlock = DispatchWorkItem(block: { [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        if !weakSelf.loggedIn {
            weakSelf.onError("Login timed out")
        }
    })

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 20, execute: self.timeoutBlock!)
}
```

And using `self.timeoutBlock?.cancel()` when leaving the ViewController or completing the process. This works as expected!